# PHP - UTF8 Decoding Issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am having problems decoding `UTF8` characters in my script from my sql.

Lets say I have two characters coming from `mysql`:

'á' & `❤️`

with my script `á` is decoded fine however, the emoticon is decoded in `â¤ï`

What am I doing wrong?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="SELECT * FROM `community` ORDER BY `community`.`date` DESC LIMIT 25";

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //UTF8

$result = $conn->query($sql); 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $comment = $row['comment'];

    echo $comment . "</br>";

    //echo htmlentities($comment); not working... white screen


}
```

**UPDATE**

I have changed Database and Tables

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="SELECT * FROM `community` ORDER BY `community`.`date` DESC LIMIT 25";

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //UTF8

$result = $conn->query($sql); 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $comment = mb_convert_encoding($comment, "UTF-8");

    echo $comment . "</br>";

    //echo htmlentities($comment); not working... white screen


}
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/476

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is probably with the database.
You need to set your database charset to UTF-8 in order to query it correctly, what you are doing is to get a string and setting **Client** side default charset using

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //UTF8
```

That's not enough, so I would recommend you to run an SQL query like

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

in order to update it. If what you need is to change a single table use

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Finally you can check it using

```
SELECT DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM data_dictionary.SCHEMAS WHERE     SCHEMA_NAME = 'databasename' LIMIT 1;
```

As an extra appointment and just in case in PHP you can convert the encoding of a string using

```
$comment = mb_convert_encoding($comment, "UTF-8");  //Change encoding  
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, "auto"); // Check encoding
```

Of course you should make a backup before making any of these changes, just in case.

EDIT: The proper order to run these queries, is:

1. Run it in the whole DB using the first query
2. Run it table by table using the second query
3. Check if the charset has been set correctly using the third query

EDIT 2 : Remember to set the tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your html file.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to change the `Collocation` to 'utf8_unicode_ci' but still have the same issue

Comment: @SNos that's because you need to change it first at the database and then in each table. I will edit the answer

Comment: I have tried changing as you suggested, I still cannot see the emoticons. In the database they are stored like: `â¤ï` and not converted by php

Comment: @SNos Ok we are getting closer, check new updates

Comment: Now I get `?` instead of  `á` and `â¤ï` still did not converted

Comment: @SNos Update your post with the results of the methods and queries I've given you to have more information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104657/discussion-between-asur-and-snos).